# Why does MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) return nothing?

Tags: mysql-5.5, myisam, full-text-search

MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('k*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

return something

Namely anything with a word that start with k

MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('ku*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
return less

MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('kuc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

return even less

we figure that more should be returned if we just use *

MATCH (FullTextSearch) AGAINST ('*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

returns nothing instead of what it should, namely EVERYTHING. Why?

Note: This means I have to specially code my sql command for empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the MySQL Documentation on Boolean mode Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) the aserisk wildcard is only applicable in the context of a word.

The engine is looking for a word that starts with whatever precedes the asterisk.  Since there is nothing preceding the asterisk, and no words start with an empty string, you get no results.